# Simple reverse dns

Tags: domain-name-system, linode

it would be $ORIGIN 113.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA. for a 255.255.255.0 netmask

but what would the origin be for a  netmask of 255.255.128.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are looking to create a reverse DNS allocation for /17 with one $ORIGIN, thats not possible and for allocations larger than a /24 block you would have to breakdown your /17 into 128 sets of /24 and use individual sets for reverse DNS.

Comment: there are other ways of doing this (e.g. with CNAMEs), but this is pretty much the easiest.

Comment: do i need $ORIGIN at all?

Comment: @Alnitak, but still one would be required to be put a PTR record somewhere right, or did I get it wrong ?

$ORIGIN is to append whatever comes after it ($ORIGIN) to your individual records, so yes put it, saves you some typing.

Comment: I guess a better question would be what is the simplest way to add reverse dns for all my virtual machines? I have it set up with a split horizon dns and want the local ips to resolve to names. I dont want to have to create 128 files.

Comment: @Gaurmire I was talking about RFC 2317 - http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2317

Answer (score 0):

The reverse DNS has nothing to do with a netmask. It is just the PTR of an IP.

So the answer is: The same!